# HTML5 Canvas Tooltips

Tags: javascript, html, tooltip, easeljs

I am using the HTML5 Canvas. I have added images (BitmapImages) to the canvas and I now want to add simple tooltips to these bitmap images.

Is this possible ??? If so can someone tell / show me how I could achieve this ?

I am not sure if it makes a difference , but I am also using the Easel JS Framework ...

Here is an example of what I currently have:

```
var container = new Container(); // EaselJS Container
container.x = 100;
container.y = 100;

stage.addChild(container);

var image = new Image();
image.src = "image.png";

var bitmap = new Bitmap(image);
bitmap.x = 5;
bitmap.y = 5;
bitmap.mouseEnabled = true;

container.addChild(bitmap);

...
```

I have not tested this code, but basically a bitmap image is created and added to my stage. I now want to add a simple tool tip to my bitmap image, but cant seem to work out how :(

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers,
Jon.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here's how I would do it:

```
stage.enableMouseOver();

bitmap.onMouseOver = function(e) {
    stage.canvas.title = 'put your tooltip text here';
}

bitmap.onMouseOut = function(e) {
    stage.canvas.title = '';
}
```

This works by using tooltips already provided by the browser.

Comment: Where would I see this tooltips? I am not seeing anything. Using impactjs

Comment: It's a browser tooltip, so it only shows if you hold your cursor over it for a second or two. You can see an example of this style of tooltip by hovering over the upvote/downvote buttons on this page.

Comment: The question does include that the Bitmaps are added to a Canvas element, meaning a "context.drawImage(bitmap)" was called. This means that they are not available as DOM elements, and are thus not creating a standard tooltip. I wonder about this answer being marked "Accepted" and even getting a reward...

Comment: @A.K-R Look at the code a bit closer. While the bitmap is not a DOM element, the stage certainly is -- the tooltip is created on the stage, not the EaselJS Bitmap object.